# Pandas timeseries data: selecting first X days of month in a range of data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, time-series

This may seem ridiculous but... How do I select only the data from the first 28 days of each month in a timeseries?

I have timeseries indexed data spanning multiple years (with data for most days).  What I have is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename')

Out: 

               Amount:
Date:
2014-07-14     76.59;
2014-07-11     1394.08;
2014-07-08     90.00;
2014-07-06     378.52;
2014-06-30     15.52;
2014-06-30     3016.53;
2014-06-30     0.29;
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make the output look like this (i.e. - no data beyond the 28th day of the month):

```
Date:          Amount:
2014-07-14     76.59;
2014-07-11     1394.08;
2014-07-08     90.00;
2014-07-06     378.52;
```

I have searched for several hours now, but I'm new to Python.  I've been reading the [Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) for Pandas time series data, but can't find anything I think would work.  I'm also new to StackOverflow so... I'm probably violating all kinds of rules.  Please be merciful.  The answer is probably obvious, but not to me.  Suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the day attribute of your index and use this to create a boolean index into your df:

```
In [66]:

df[df.index.day <= 28]
Out[66]:
             Amount
Date               
2014-07-14    76.59
2014-07-11  1394.08
2014-07-08    90.00
2014-07-06   378.52
```

A list of other attributes can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was something obvious.  Thanks for the link too.  That will be coming in handy.